# Save location data in SQLite to show in Google Map API 2 on request in fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I need some inputs on how to tackle this task Im trying to solve..
In a fragment (A) you can add a new customer to a SQLite DB. In another Listfragment (B) i show all customers in the DB, but the thing is I want to be able to show their location on a map when you tap the customer in the list.
SO first of all i need to save some data about the location when inserting the customer in fragment A, but what data is that? Can the user just enter the address in a address field, save that to the DB, and in Google maps API 2 show the location based on a normal address? Or is it only LatLong? And how would i save that dataset based on the customer address?

I have my API 2 map in my fragment C (the one showing on list item click) and the map is setup with a MapView in the onCreateView:

```
private GoogleMap map;
MapView m;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_detail, container, false);

    m = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = m.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to resolve latitude and longitude from location name. And then you can store this coordinates in your database.

Comment: Aha, thanks - looks like what i need. How should i save the data?

Comment: @MacLuc just write lat and long to SQLite db.

Comment: It was just how it returned the latlong data, but I will look into that.